# JSON data querying by breeze

Tags: javascript, json, breeze, single-page-application

I attempting my first SPA.

It will be a HTML representation of the model of our database structure to give to clients to look through the model and do queries of the database model (not the database data itself).

The requirement is then for no updates and the SPA will be shipped with the release and thus will be offline. Currently it is a static HTML page.

My question is - is there a way to use breeze to query the json file I've created that describes the model? All I've seen are examples of the EntityManager being initialised with a service URL - that will return the data.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand the question. What do you mean by (no server)?. Does this mean that you want to bring all of the data down just once and then query it locally?

If the data that you want to query is actually itself metadata then if you describe the structure of the metadata (i.e. metadata of metadata) in Breeze's native metadata format, then you should be able to query the metadata itself via Breeze's EntityQuery.

Probably a little more info would be helpful.

Also, take a look at the Breeze NoDb sample for an example of "custom" metadata construction.

Comment: Offline = no server. Yes generate the HTML, CSS and JSON data when we do a release, resulting in a SPA that does not update only query.

Comment: So the HTML, CSS and JSON will all be in local files, never served from a server? If so, my answer above still stands, and the NoDb sample is still a good example of how to define metadata.

Comment: So after I tell the EntityManager about the metadata. I need to Create each entity via the EntityManager.CreateEntity "e.g. new customer = manager.createEntity('Customer', { Name: "Acme" });" instead of just getting the EntityManager to load my JSON data file? I found this in Extending Entities in the breeze documentation referenced in the NoDb sample.